# Haxe jQuery check if HTML/images has finished loading

Tags: jquery, haxe

I am building an app using Haxe and jQuery Extern.

I am adding normal HTML (includes images) to a container, I want to check when the content is loaded.

I know in normal jQuery it's (where 'window' is changeable with selectors) :

```
$(window).load(function(){/*loaded*/});
```

**How can I achieve this in Haxe?**

Comment: It looks like you have it figured out. What's the question?

Comment: Haxe is a bit different than "normal" jQuery...

Comment: Ah. I'll get my nose out of your question now. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why you want to use jQuery for such tasks, it can be done with native Haxe too. Haxe doesn't reinvent how the DOM works. Below is how I guess all should work.

**window load**

javascript

```
 $(window).load(function(){
   //your magic codes
 });
```

haxe

```
 new JQuery(js.Browser.window).on('load', function(event) {
   //your magic codes
 });
```

native haxe (nearly the same as plain javascript)

```
 var window = js.Browser.window;
 window.addEventListener("load", function() {
   //your magic codes
 });
```

**image load**

javascript

```
 $("#myImage").load(function(){
   //your magic codes
 });
```

haxe

```
 new JQuery("#myImage").on('load', function(event) {
   //your magic codes
 });
```

native haxe (nearly the same as plain javascript)

```
 var document = js.Browser.document;
 document.getElementById("myImage").addEventListener("load", function() {
   //your magic codes
 });
```

**DOM ready**

javascript

```
 $(function(){
   //your magic codes
 });
```

haxe

```
 new JQuery(function():Void {
   //your magic codes
 });
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I will use your examples to make it work for html containers etc. (Works perfectly for images)

Answer (score 0):

i use it like this:

http://try.haxe.org/#7F46d

be sure to remove your listener :)

Comment: Thanks for this - How would you use your method to check when a html container with all it's children are finished loading?